# How to apply set function to all the rows of a specific column whose entries are list having repeated values?

Tags: python, pandas

In my pandas data frame, I have a column where each row of the column is a list with repeated values. For example - A data frame with 3 rows:
`df = pd.DataFrame({'Column_1': [[1,2,3,2],[1,1,2],[1,2,3]]})`
I want to remove the duplicates. My expected output is something like `[[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,2,3]]`. How can I apply a set function to remove the duplicates in each of the lists?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you are searching is to remove duplicates in a list.
Refer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists

Comment: Right but I want to apply a set function to the entries of dataframe's column directly. I am looking for an efficient way to do this in pandas. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `df`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column_1': [[1,2,3,2],[1,1,2],[1,2,3]]})
```

Try:

```
df.Column_1 = df.Column_1.apply(lambda r : list(set(r)))
```

or:

```
df.Column_1 = df.Column_1.apply(np.unique)
```

result:

```
    Column_1
0  [1, 2, 3]
1     [1, 2]
2  [1, 2, 3]
```